# Can't locate Autom4te/ChannelDefs.pm in @INC (when it definitely is there)

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, autoconf

I've been running into trouble running `make` for a build process that I know works on a 32-bit Ubuntu VM. I am running a 64-bit Ubuntu VM, and I have a feeling that the 64-bit may be the problem, but am not entirely sure.

Basically, when I run the make command, I get the following error:

```
Can't locate Autom4te/ChannelDefs.pm in @INC (@INC contains: [...]/staging_dir/host/share/autoconf /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at [...]/staging_dir/host/bin/autoreconf line 40.
```

Now if I navigate to `[...]/staging_dir/host/share/autoconf` I can see that, contrary to what autoreconf thinks, `Autom4te/ChannelDefs.pm` definitely exists, so I don't really understand what's going on here.

To fix previous (64 vs 32 bit) problems I've also installed `ia32-libs`, and installed `autoconf` just to be safe, but it's still giving me this weird error.

Comment: Actually I've just tried it on a 32-bit machine and I get the same error.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? In that case you should post an answer, I'd be happy to know.

Comment: Yes, see my answer: basically I have no idea exactly what solved it, but I have a feeling it was probably all the permissions stuff.

Comment: I got this error when running `dpkg-buildpackage`. What solved was to run it on `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I solved the problem, but I'm not sure exactly which combination of things solved it. I did a lot of permissions fixing (especially +x ing binaries).

Answer (score 0):

Perl can't find the path of the Autom4te lib, create a soft link from `/usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/share/autoconf` to `/usr/local/share`.The command like:
`cd /usr/local/share && ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/share/autoconf .`.
Oh, This is MacOS

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this problem was caused by the incorrect prefix path where I installed the binaries: I have first installed them to one folder and then moved to another.

The lesson: double-check that all paths are correct and you didn't move anything from one place to another manually.

(I was building the RTEMS OS according to its "Quick Start" instructions, macOS 10.14)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing "autoconf" package

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```